# FOSRest validation form

Tags: fosrestbundle

What's the best way to obtain this response to invalid form?
[Response example of an invalid form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#forms-and-views)

Actually I have this action

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }


    $errors = $form->getErrors(true);
    $view = $this->view($errors);

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

But the response is the next json object:

```
{ form: Object, errors: Array }
```

I work with JMSSerializerBundle. I saw in `FormErrorNormalizer` class the method `normalize` in FOSRestBundle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`Request`'s `handleRequest` is for html forms. You have to use `submit` instead for FOSREST.

```
$form->submit($Request->getContent());
```